# Nexgen gallery wordpress not showing images

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, gallery

I have updated the Nexgen gallery plugin and it stop showing the galleries on the page which I am getting by custom PHP code.

Here is code which I am using for getting gallery.

```
$nggdb = new nggdb();
$images = $nggdb->get_gallery($post->post_name, 'sortorder', 'ASC', true, 0, 0);
foreach($images as $i=>$image) {
    // list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize($image->url);
    // $ratio = (float)$originalWidth / $originalHeight;

    // if($ratio > 1.2) {
        // $class = "width-2";
    // } else {
        // $class = "";
    // }

    ?>
    <a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $image->imageURL; ?>">
        <div class="grid-item col-md-3  col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <img src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL; ?>" />
            <?php
            if($image->_ngiw->_cache['description'] != "") {
                ?>
                <div class="title">
                    <?php echo $image->_ngiw->_cache['description']; ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: Any errors? Downgrade the plugin? Check the nextgen gallery page? It's quite active, if you only upgraded the plugin and it stopped working you're not the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change post_name with post ID and its start working..

```
$images = $nggdb->get_gallery($post->ID, 'sortorder', 'ASC', true, 0, 0);
```

so here is correct code..